useTemplateRef is not reactive for arrays?
I'd like to react to changes made to an array of template ref elements created with a v-for loop over some collection of arbitrary objects. I'd like to pass this array to a component / composable and have it react to the changes.
The docs provide a way to save these elements to an array: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#refs-inside-v-for
I've modified the provided example to see, if the resulting itemsRef array would be reactive. The code is:
<script setup>
import { ref, useTemplateRef, watch, markRaw } from 'vue'

const list = ref([1, 2, 3])

const itemRefs = useTemplateRef('items')

watch(itemRefs, () => {
  console.log("itemsRef:", itemRefs.value.length);
}, {deep: true});

watch(list, () => {
  console.log("list:", list.value.length, itemRefs.value.length);
}, { deep: true });
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="list.push(list.length + 1)">add</button>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in list" ref="items">
      {{ item }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>

But the return value of useTemplateRef seems to be a ShallowRef, judging from its TypeScript signature:
function useTemplateRef<T>(key: string): Readonly<ShallowRef<T | null>>

So the watch on itemRefs really runs just once:

As you can see, array's contents are changing (list is updated), but the changes to itemRefs are not captured by vue. I tried making the watch deep, but it does not help.
Is there a way to make the ref not shallow somehow? Or maybe there is another way?


const { createApp, ref, useTemplateRef, watch, markRaw } = Vue;

const app = createApp({
  setup() {
    const list = ref([1, 2, 3]);

    const itemRefs = useTemplateRef('items');

    watch(itemRefs, () => {
      console.log("itemsRef: ", itemRefs.value.length);
    }, { deep: true });

    watch(list, () => {
      console.log("list: ", list.value.length, itemRefs.value.length);
    }, { deep: true });
    
    return { list }
  }
});

app.mount('#app');
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button @click="list.push(list.length + 1)">add</button>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in list" ref="items">
      {{ item }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>




Using const elements = ref([]) with ref="elements" inside a v-for does not guarantee order, as per vue's docs.
Also, if your ref="elements" is a Component, the elements array will be full of ComponentPublicInstance elements.
To battle this, I used this gist as the base and created this composable:
export const useTemplateRefs = (elements: Ref<HTMLElement[]>) => {
  onBeforeUpdate(() => {
    elements.value = [];
  });
  const setElement = (elem: Element | ComponentPublicInstance | null, index: number): void => {
    if (elem == null) {
      return;
    }
    if (elem instanceof Element) {
      if (elem instanceof HTMLElement) {
        elements.value[index] = elem;
        return;
      }
    } else if (elem.$el instanceof HTMLElement) {
      elements.value[index] = elem.$el;
      return;
    }
    throw new Error("Unexpected element type");
  };
  return setElement;
};

Which can be used this way:
<script setup lang="ts">
const messages = ref([{id: 1, text: "Message"}]);
const messageRefs = ref<HTMLElement[]>([]);
const setRef = useTemplateRefs(messageRefs);
</script>

<template>
  <div class="container">
  <div
      v-for="(message, index) in messages"
      :key="message.id"
      :ref="el => setRef(el, index)"
    >
      {{ message.text }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

Now the messageRefs array is fully reactive and is in full sync with messages array.

itemRefs is updated (e.g reactive). But it's always updated 1 render cycle after list has changed.
Wrap your console.log in nextTick (imported from 'vue') and the numbers will match:


const { createApp, ref, useTemplateRef, watch, nextTick } = Vue

const app = createApp({
  setup() {
    const list = ref([1, 2, 3])
    const itemRefs = useTemplateRef('items')
    watch(
      itemRefs,
      () => {
        console.log('itemsRef: ', itemRefs.value.length)
      },
      { deep: true }
    )
    watch(
      list,
      () => {
        nextTick(() =>
          console.log('list: ', list.value.length, itemRefs.value.length)
        )
      },
      { deep: true }
    )
    return { list }
  }
})

app.mount('#app')
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button @click="list.push(list.length + 1)">add</button>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in list" ref="items">
      {{ item }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>



Also note you can't watch it deeply, since it's a shallow ref. To be able to get this functionality, use a normal ref:


const { createApp, ref, watch, nextTick } = Vue

const app = createApp({
  setup() {
    const list = ref([1, 2, 3])
    const items = ref([])
    watch(
      items,
      () => {
        console.log('itemsRef: ', items.value.length)
      },
      { deep: true }
    )
    watch(
      list,
      () => {
        nextTick(() =>
          console.log('list: ', list.value.length, items.value.length)
        )
      },
      { deep: true }
    )
    return { list, items }
  }
})

app.mount('#app')
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button @click="list.push(list.length + 1)">add</button>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in list" ref="items">
      {{ item }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>




Sorry, I must've not been clear enough. I want to watch itemRefs and receive updates. I only watch list in the example just for the sake of example. I'd like to pass itemRefs to a component / composable and have it react to the changes.

@winwin, shallow refs can't be watched deeply, by design. Find another way :)

So there is no point in using useTemplateRef for arrays of template refs, then?

Well, it's designed for Typescrpt support mainly. Watch the actual source of the change (whatever is affecting items). You can also use const items = ref([]) (whithout useTemplateRefs()) and it should be deeply watchable.

yes, this seems to be working. I will accept the answer, if you modified it. I made a snippet with changes to the code, which I can attach to your answer.

Updated to include the suggestion in my previous comment.

I noticed that your answer does not work for refs, where ref is a component instance. I wrote my implementation for this case.
